# Title and DOI are combined in Elsevier BST file

Tags: bibtex

I'm using the bibliography style file "elsarticle-num.bst" for Elsevier (link is [here](http://www.elsevier.com/__data/assets/file/0006/109365/elsarticle-num.bst)). I'd like to include the DOI for journal articles but when I compile there is no space between the title and "doi:". For example it will say:

> W. Cornelius, L. W. Huellmantel, H. R. Mitchell, Ammonia as an engine
>   fueldoi:10.4271/650052.

How do I add a space? The BST file is opaque at best. Thanks.

The entry itself:

```
@ARTICLE{Cornelius1965, 
   author = {Cornelius, Walter and Huellmantel, L. William and Mitchell, Harry R.}, 
   title = {Ammonia as an Engine Fuel}, 
   year = {1965}, 
   month = {Feb}, 
   doi = {10.4271/650052}, 
   owner = {em793}, 
   publisher = {SAE International}, 
   timestamp = {2014.03.14} 
}
```

Comment: Please post the bib entry in question.

Comment: From the DOI itself: @ARTICLE{Cornelius1965,
  author = {Cornelius, Walter and Huellmantel, L. William and Mitchell, Harry
 R.},
  title = {Ammonia as an Engine Fuel},
  year = {1965},
  month = {Feb},
  doi = {10.4271/650052},
  owner = {em793},
  publisher = {SAE International},
  timestamp = {2014.03.14}
}

Comment: Thanks for this follow-up. I've taken the liberty of copying the information into the body of the posting, where it'll be more easily seen by readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the problem arises because there is no journal given, which is expected to come after the title in an ARTICLE entry. Cite it as a book (which is how Google Scholar provides it, as you can see [at the search results](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=Ammonia+as+an+Engine+Fuel) by choosing "Cite" and "Import into BibTeX".)

Comment: Good catch that the entry isn't an article published in a journal! Should `@book` not be correct, maybe `@misc` will do.

Comment: By the way, when I try to follow the link you've provided, I get a "403. That's an error" message.

Comment: @Kundor- You were correct. The example that I provided was listed as an article, but is actually more of a Tech Report. When I switched the entry type in JabRef, the problem went away. Many thanks!

Comment: @Mico: Thanks for letting me know. The link persists in working for me, but I guess I'm special! Hopefully linking to the search results works.